# how to fix React hook error "React Hook "React.useState" is called conditionally"?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I have error when trying to build next.js project. How can I fix it?
I understood, that the purpose of error is using hooks conditionally.

```
./src/lib/session.js
6:29  Error: React Hook "React.useState" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render.  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
10:3  Error: React Hook "React.useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

import React from 'react'

export const useSessionStorage = (storageKey, fallbackState) => {
  if (typeof window == 'undefined') { return [fallbackState, null] }
  
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(
    JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(storageKey)) ?? fallbackState
  )

  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(value))
  }, [value, storageKey])

  return [value, setValue]
}

export const getFromStorage = (key) => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.localstorage.getItem(key)
  }
}

export const setToStorage = (key, value) => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    return window.localstorage.setItem(key, value)
  }
}
```

Comment: useState/useEffect may not be called if `window` isn't defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the problem in your code: hooks should not be used conditionally.

In your code, the condition

```
if (typeof window == 'undefined') { return [fallbackState, null] }
```

Must be written after the hooks, so just before

```
return [value, setValue]
```